# How to nest a list of objects into another and how to do it elegantly?

Tags: javascript, object, nested-lists

I have two objects coming from two SQL queries: *posts* and *comments*. Now I want to create one "posts"-object with "comments" objects nested in each of the posts. If I JOIN that data in SQL, I get a flat object without nesting. I need it nested thought. I tried the following method in two for loops, but this did not work because the new_object_line does not have a comments key (yet).

```
joined_object = Object.assign(new_object_line.comments, rows_comments[x])
```

Original posts list object:

```
var posts =
{
   post1:
   {
       title: 'Title 1',
       id: id1
   }
   post2:
   {
       title: 'Title 2',
       id: id2
   }
   post3:
   {
       title: 'Title 3',
       id: id3
       
   }
}
```

Original comments list object:

```
var comments = 
{
    comment1: {
        text: 'aaa',
        belongs_to_post: id2
    }

    comment2: {
        text: 'bbb',
        belongs_to_post: id2
    }

    comment3: {
        text: 'ccc',
        belongs_to_post: id3
    }
}
```

This is how the result object *joined_object* with posts including comments should look like:

```
var joined_object = 
    {
       post1:
       {
           title: 'Title 1',
           id: 1
       }
       post2:
       {
           title: 'Title 2',
           id: 2
           comments: 
           {

                comment1: {
                    text: 'aaa',
                    belongs_to_post: id2
                }
    
                comment2: {
                    text: 'bbb',
                    belongs_to_post: id2
                }
           }
       }
       
       post3:
       {
           title: 'Title 3',
           id: 3
           comments: 

           {
              comment3: {
                text: 'ccc',
                belongs_to_post: id3
              }
           } 
       }
    }
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. A mere “I want” is not a proper question, and we are not here to write tutorials. You need to show an attempt at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the expected output using `for..in` loop by matching the id:

```js
for(let o in posts){
    for(let c in comments){
        if(posts[o].id == comments[c].belongs_to_post){
            // (posts[o].comments ??={})[c] = comments[c]
               posts[o].comments = posts[o].comments || {};
               posts[o].comments[c] = comments[c];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks. When I try your code the if statement fires (a match is found) but the assignment fails with " SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??=' ". I am too noob yet to understand why. I am not sure how that "??=" notation works, would you have a link explaining that notation?

Comment: @A.T. this is logical nullish operator, read more about it here .. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment

Comment: Gorak, your code actually works. But I think it creates a nested object like this:
comments: {'0': [TextRow], '1': [TextRow], ...} instead of comments: { [TextRow], [TextRow], ...}

Comment: @A.T. it will produces the output which you have shared in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I am lost a bit. I got a structure now like following. But when I run posts[0].comments.length i get undefined, although I expect it to be 2 because I have two comments there. I suppose it has something to do that the key is '0'. Structure: ... comments: { '0': TextRow { id: 1, text: 'aaa' }, '1': TextRow { id: 2, text: 'bbb' } }

Comment: I think I got it. I suppose it has to be: Object.keys(posts[0].comments).length to work

Comment: do you want `comments` to be an array ? If so then make `posts[o].comments` as an array instead of object. and push the further comments in to that.

Comment: gorak, thanks for help. I suppose, I am still generally confused if what I get back from MySQL in those regular queries are full scale arrays (posts and comments), full scale objects - or arrays containing full scale objects ([posts], [comments]). Right now I have the crazy situation that I can do `posts.length` but not `posts[0].comments.length`. It seems that now I have object-comments in a posts array. I need to read up on this. I am not sure what to google for though.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is almost perfectly fine, but in reality you're much more likely to have an array of post objects like so:

```
const posts = [
   {
      "title":"Title 1",
      "id":1
   },
   {
      "title":"Title 2",
      "id":2,
      "comments":[
         {
            "text":"aaa",
            "belongs_to_post":2
         },
         {
            "text":"bbb",
            "belongs_to_post":2
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Title 3",
      "id":3,
      "comments":[
         {
            "text":"ccc",
            "belongs_to_post":3
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

As you can see - you now don't have a property on an object that contains your post, rather just a list of posts (Which I would assume matches your database results more closely).

Now, if you'd like to get return a single post based on id, you would do the following:

```
const postTwo = posts.filter(post => post.id === 2);
```

You can then access comments on the post 2 easily:

```
const comments = postTwo.comments;
```

Take a look into JSON objects basics here, with examples of nested objects:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: Phil, you mean because it is an array which comes from a SQL query? Yeh, I suppose you are right. But does this change the general problem of nesting objects into each other somehow,  if the objects are stuck in an array?

Comment: That's what I meant - you're getting a list back from a SQL query - so why try and create an object that holds each result as a property, when arrays exist for this purpose!

Nested objects aren't really a problem. Whilst they might be overwhelming when they are many levels deep, they bring a logical hierarchal order to your data.

If you think of posts as an entity, and comments as another - it would be right to assume that posts "contain" a list of comments. (Or in a SQL viewpoint - There's a one to many link between posts and comments).

Comment: It may also be worth reading about JS classes, personally I find they help build cohesive picture of your data model: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: My classes are basically exactly like that: posts and comments. Those are separate tables in the database. And yes they are related by post id: posts can have many comments. If I use a sql JOIN of those tables, it gives me a flat object (in an array) and not a nested one. But for my view (posts_listing.ejs in nodejs) I need the comments nested into the posts. That is where my suffering starts.

Comment: I would've thought that flattening the objects to a single JS Object would've been more problematic than nesting them in the Node ecosystem.
For example, let's say a user has the ability to delete a comment on Post 2 in the example. How do you loop through properties on an object to find out which comment to remove from the list? You'd need to do something like `post[\`comment${index}\`]`. Using nested objects, you can use the filter method from my answer to get the post by id.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with objects, you can use something like lodash and I'd suggest something like this:

```js
const { mapValues, filter, isEmpty } = require('lodash')

const joined = mapValues(posts, post => {
  const byPostId = { belongs_to_post: post.id }
  const relatedComments = filter(comments, byPostId)

  if (isEmpty(relatedComments)) {
    return post
  }

  return { ...post, comments: relatedComments }
})

console.log(joined)
```